# What the difference between designated and convenience init in this code below

Tags: swift, initialization

There are two parts of code, there result seems same in the *.playground, So that make me a little confused, so what the exactly difference between designated and convenience init in this code below, and how could I know when should I use a convenience init rather than a designated init?

Part 1

```
class Food {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "[Unnamed]")
    }
}

let food  = Food()
let food2 = Food(name: "Rice")
```

Part 2

```
class Food {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    init() {
        self.name = "[Unnamed]"
    }

}

let food  = Food()
let food2 = Food(name: "Rice")
```

In part 1 and part 2 the different part are

```
//part 1
convenience init() {
    self.init(name: "[Unnamed]")
}

//part 2
init() {
    self.name = "[Unnamed]"
}
```

Comment: see apple Doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Comment: @Carrl Hey, I just found some description which I thought may useful, "You do not have to provide convenience initializers if your class does not require them. Create convenience initializers whenever a shortcut to a common initialization pattern will save time or make initialization of the class clearer in intent."  But it still don't make sense to me, how to explain my code above, two different way got the same  result@_@

Comment: this is because you have no parameter in both of your init function. Normally, You can use less parameter in convenience init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference arises in subclasses; in what you've shown there is no usage difference.

“Convenience initializers must always delegate across” meaning in class `A` a convenience initializers calls a designated initializers in class `A`.  “Designated initializers must always delegate up” meaning class `B`, a subclass of `A`, calls designated initializers in `A`.

Thus, in your 'part 2' both of the initializers in `Food` are available to subclasses of `Food`.  But, in your 'part 1', only one initializer can be used in subclasses.

For example (`Food` in the following is your 'part 1'):

```
 21> class Fat : Food { 
 22.     init () { 
 23.         super.init() 
 24.     } 
 25. }    
repl.swift:23:9: error: must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'Food'
        super.init()
        ^
```

Quotes are: Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: Many thanks, I read the relevant part in the book again and understand what you mean. But there still a question confused me, the designated init in superclass could be override in subclass but convenience init cannot, so when should I use convenience init rather than designated init, is there any  advantage?